# Как поменять фон Яндекс.Карт?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, yandex-maps-api

Например, вот на такой, серый; заранее спасибо за помощь

[image: чёрно-белая карта]

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам то прошу палец вверх и защитать его верным)чтоб была мотивация так скажем)

Answer (score 2):

Бёрем этот код

```
<style>
[class*="ymaps-2"][class*="-ground-pane"] {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
</style>
```

И вставляем в секцию head нашего Muse-сайта.
Делает именно так как вы просили серым.)

Comment: Ахах) еще никогда не делал сайты на muse, вставил этот код себе работает, но мне надо адекватно поменять бэкграунд, так как я не хочу добавлять этот кусок кода а хочу скажем одними css стилями, сам что-то не могу разобраться. подскажите пожалуйста. Пока что вам ставлю палец вверх, а как подскажите естественно сделаю ответ верным

Comment: Все уже разобрался, можете не отвечать, за помощь спасибо!!

Comment: хотя вижу есть проблемка в том что filter не работает в IE, возможно можно как-то наложить свойством например background нужный цвет? Ну чтобы все браузеры отображали карту так как надо, заранее спасибо!

Comment: @LiEm Добавьте filter: gray;